# How to Train on plain text paragraphs and return keyphrases? is that even possible?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am working on keyphrase extraction, right now I was able to create some features and run the candidate phrases along with the features for training a machine learning model for classification using the random forest.

Now out of curiosity, I want trying out deep learning as I want to remove the layer of feature extraction manually and I want it to figure out the features by itself and generate a model by just passing some text documents and the relative key phrases(1/0 whether correct or incorrect) for each document, I want to know, does any training model accept plain text instead of float values and if not how do i try achieving the same by converting the sentences and keyphrases to floating values and pass to the training model

Even tried creating a model using Keras Sequential model (sample given)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(18, input_dim=14, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(14, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=300, batch_size=10)
```

`Please provide me any informative resources to start and has code samples as well.`

Comment: a really nice work has been done to use BERT as tool for text summarization (i suspect this is what you want). Here a nice article to help you in this direction (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.09243.pdf - (out April 12)). You can also use an embedding layer at the beginning of the network to get from words to float automatically(you just map words to integers first but this is not a ML part).

Comment: Is every document tagged with one keyphrase or multiple keyphrases ?

Comment: @mujjiga every document is tagged with multiple keyphrases.

Answer (score 5):

You can use word2Vector to convert each word to a vector, there are some pre-trained word vector out there. For instance google news(300 features each word), Wikipedia(400 features each word). These are general word vectors. If your contents are from some particular sources, you can use gensim to train your own word vectors. You can define feature length as you want(100 or even fewer). As your own word vector don't have to cover words as many as google and wikipedia. Use word vector represent a word, and you sentence or phrases will be a sequence of vector. Then you can use RNN, GRU, or LSTM any kinds of time series model to train a kernel. To predict 1 or 0 as keyphrase or not. Also called named entity recognition.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information,I would like to know how would I convert an entire passage to a word vector as I have multiple passages to train and it will not always be the same number of words in them how would i deal with this, Iam completely now to thigs, it would be great if you could update your answer with some reference links, please.

Comment: Here is an example https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/   As you said, the passage won't be the same length, this could be a feature missing problem. Depend on the data and application itself, there are lot of different solutions. The easiest way is just give all 0s for blank positions, if they are shorter than the longest one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Embedding` layer in Keras, which is essentially a lookup table: from word index to the corresponding word vector, which is trained with the rest of the network. Before passing your text to this layer, you need to encode your text into the sequence of word indices.

As a result, you will get a variable-length vector of word vectors. To process it, you can encode it with recurrent layers, as Jiajie Yu suggests, or with convolutional layers and 1D pooling (some say that convolutions are more suitable for keyphrase extraction).

A toy example of preprocessing the text and using an embedding layer you can get [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-word-embedding-layers-deep-learning-keras/), using convolutions on top of it - [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_cnn.py), and LSTM - [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py). And [this](https://nlpforhackers.io/lstm-pos-tagger-keras/) is an example of using embedding + LSTM to predict POS tag for each word; you can easily modify it to predict whether the word belongs to a keyphrase instead.

Comment: Does universal-sentence-encoder by tensor flow help me for encoding and decoding the sentences ?

Comment: If you want to solve the problem on sentence level (like sentence classification), then yes, it would be helpful. But the problem you stated looks more like a problem on word level (you want to jointly classify all words into key and non-key). If it is indeed the case, you must have preserve local information, but USE loses it. So I think you want to use USE only as an additional feature extractor, with word-level encoder as the main one.